# Un gobelet à popcorn, un gobelet de popcorn

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour, quelle est la différence entre :

- un gobelet **à** popcorn et un gobelet **de** popcorn
- une bouteille **à** vin et une bouteille **de** vin

Je pense qu'on utilise le mot « à » pour désigner un objet qui n'est pas encore rempli et qui sert juste de sorte de conteneur, et « de » pour désigner un conteneur qui est déjà rempli avec les aliments parce qu'on utilise « de » pour les quantités.

Je n'en suis pas sûre. Merci.

Comment: De mes souvenirs de sorties ciné, je n'aurais pas dit "gobelet" mais "seau".

Comment: Attention, la réponse acceptée affirme que les deux sont le plus souvent interchangeables, c'est inexact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vous avez répondu à votre question. Un gobelet **à** popcorn est la description du récipient destiné à contenir du popcorn, il est peut-être encore vide, vous l'avez peut-être rempli avec autre chose bien qu'il soit destiné techniquement au popcorn. La même logique s'applique à la bouteille. Un gobelet (ou seau) **de** popcorn désigne le récipient **contenant** du popcorn, il est possible qu'il ne soit pas spécifiquement destiné à ça, c'est valable aussi pour la bouteille. Le plus souvent, on utilise les deux termes d'une manière interchangeable.

Comment: Je suis d'accord en grande partie avec cette réponse mais pour moi les deux termes ne sont pas réellement interchangeables. "J'ai pris un gobelet de popcorn" implique que le gobelet contient du popcorn contrairement à "J'ai pris un gobelet à popcorn", qui, pour moi, signifie pratiquement que le gobelet est vide.

Comment: Il ne sont pas interchangeable d'une manière purement linguistique mais dans le language commun on les utilise d'un manière equivalente.

Comment: Ben non, justement, on ne les utilise pas de manière équivalente. *N'oublie pas de prendre un verre de vin* ne signifie pas du tout la même chose que *n'oublie pas de prendre un verre à vin*.

Comment: PS: quand on répond à quelqu'un qui n'est ni l'auteur de la question, ni l'auteur de la réponse à laquelle on ajoute un commentaire, il ne faut pas oublier d'utiliser l'arobase suivie du pseudo du destinataire, ici @vc74

Comment: je n'ai jamais vraiment entendu parler de "bouteille à vin", une bouteille de vin, même vide, reste une bouteille de vin pour moi, et si il faut vraiment lever l'ambiguité, on parlera d'une bouteille de vin vide.

Comment: @LaurentS. Quand tu m'inviteras chez toi, j'apporterai une bouteille de vin ! ;-) [Anjou](https://www.wiki-anjou.fr/index.php/Bouteille_%C3%A0_vin_d%27Anjou) [Québec](https://www.archeolab.quebec/familles-d-objets/bouteilles-a-boissons-alcoolisees)